# VB Script to create guid based on creted date time

Tags: vba, vb6, guid

I have the following VB Scrtip that I use in excel to generate a GUID. Ideally I want the GUID to be based on date time created not just randomly. Is there anyway to amend this script to build the GUID based on date and time?

```
 Private Type GUID
 Data1 As Long
 Data2 As Long
 Data3 As Long
 Data4(8) As Byte
 Private Declare Function CoCreateGuid _
 Lib "ole32.dll" _
 (ByRef pGUID As GUID) As Long

 Private Declare Function StringFromGUID2 _
 Lib "ole32.dll" _
 (ByRef rGUID As Any, _
 ByVal lpstrCLSID As Long, _
 ByVal cbMax As Long) As Long

 Function CreateGUID() As String

 Dim b() As Byte
 Dim BuffSize As Long
 Dim RetVal As Long
 Dim MyGUID As GUID
 BuffSize = 40
 ReDim b(BuffSize * 2) As Byte  
 RetVal = CoCreateGuid(MyGUID)
 RetVal = StringFromGUID2(MyGUID, VarPtr(b(0)), BuffSize)
 CreateGUID = Left$(b, RetVal - 1)
 End Function
```

Many thanks

Comment: What exactly are you after? there are GUID implementations that swap out the last part of data4 with a timestamp, and there are sequential GUIDs .. why do you need them not to be in their natural state of randomness?

Comment: I know it can be done with CombGuid. But cant figure out way a using VBS. I would prefer to use this CombGuid format to avoid index fragmentation. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you want this in vbs/vba or vb6 (as the example), you mention indexing are you using sql server?

Answer (score 0):

GUIDs do normally have a date/time component, among other data. If you want them not to be GUIDs, you can make up any string you want, but you need to come up with your own method of avoiding collisions, especially with real GUIDs.

Comment: I really wasn't aware that GUIDs were related to tipe/date... Isn't it just related to MAC adress? Or am I confusing something?

Comment: They are made up of several parts depending on the [version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guid#Algorithm), the original spec used a mac address.